# How is socket object created without the new keyword but with the socketserver method accept()

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to read some code of Java socket programming. To create a socket object I expect code like

```
Socket s = new Socket(StringIP, intPort);
```

But what I saw in example was

```
ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(portNum);
Socket socket = myServer.accept();
```

I do not understand how a socket object is created without the new keyword but with a seversocket method.
Thanks!

I am trying to create a socket object.

Comment: The server *listens* on a socket, then accepts connections to that socket when the client dials the socket.  In the end, the server (which has already begun listening) accepts the connection, and the client end up with two ends of "the same" socket.

Comment: Thanks. But my main focus here is why an object can be created without the new keyword but with a method. I think the command which creates the socket object violates java syntax.

Comment: @Jack Violates it how? Are there no other methods in the world that return objects? Is not an object type a valid type for a method? and a `return` statement?

Comment: @Jack: *" violates java syntax"* - if it would violate the _syntax_ then it would not compile. It might violate what you experienced as the common programming pattern to create objects, but where does it say that methods should not or cannot internally create objects and return these?

Comment: @Jack See Java Language Specification, (1) [`return` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17), (2) [Method declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4), and (3) [Method invocation expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). Then tell us what part of those syntaxes has been violated.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich You are right and I found the source code. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

The source code for `ServerSocket.accept()` is:

```
public Socket accept() throws IOException {
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    if (!isBound())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is not bound yet");
    Socket s = new Socket((SocketImpl) null);
    implAccept(s);
    return s;
}
```

So, as you can see, the returned `Socket` is actually created with `new`.

Comment: Not that `new` is the only way to create an object in Java. There are at least two others.